# Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET 5, Gulp task not copying files from node_modules

Tags: npm, gulp, asp.net-core, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to alter a task runner script that I borrowed from [here](https://florian.ec/articles/frontend-dependencies-npm/), however; after the task runner successfully executes in **Visual Studio 2015's Task Runner Explorer** -- the files are not actually copied.

Here is the altered script:

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='copy-assets' />
"use strict";

var _    = require('lodash'),
    gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('copy-assets', function() {
    var assets = {
        js: [
            './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
            './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            './node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
            './node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js',
            './node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
            './node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js',
            './node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
            './node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js'
        ],
        css: ['./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css']
    };
    _(assets).forEach(function(assets, type) {
        gulp.src(assets).pipe(gulp.dest('./webroot/' + type));
    });
});
```

The task runner seems to run without error in **Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise**, but there are no files in my *wwwroot/js* or *wwwroot/css* afterwards?

[image]

Here is the file structure:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?  Any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Minor oversight... unfortunately gulp silently creates the directory **webroot** and copies the files into it, it should be **wwwroot**.  Oops!!

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='copy-assets' />
"use strict";

var _    = require('lodash'),
    gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('copy-assets', function() {
    var assets = {
        js: [
            './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
            './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            './node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
            './node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js',
            './node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
            './node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js',
            './node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
            './node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js'
        ],
        css: ['./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css']
    };
    _(assets).forEach(function(assets, type) {
        gulp.src(assets).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/' + type));
    });
});
```

:punch: