# Is the .NET Core 1.0 SDK still in Preview 2?

Tags: .net-core

I tried to download the .NET Core 1.0 SDK. However, when I download it from the [official location](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows), and try to install, it says that it's ".NET Core 1.0.1, SDK 1.0.0 SDK Preview 2".

Is there a 1.0 version or any other version that is not in preview or RC stage? If so, where can I get it?

I am aware that RC **is** supported for production. However, isn't there a version that is not in preview or RC stage yet?

[image: .net core sdk installer]

Answer (score 2):

There are two different things going on here, which can be confusing:

The **.NET Core API** (packages and libraries) are 1.0 and considered stable. There was recently a minor update to some packages (1.0.1) to fix some bugs.

The **.NET Core tooling**, including support in Visual Studio 2015, is considered "preview". There are still some bugs, and the project file formats will change in the future (project.json [will go away](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537047/3191599)).

In short, the code is stable and the tools are still evolving. The way the installer phrases it makes it extra confusing.