# Missing type/namespace in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I've created an empty ASP.NET Core Mvc project in visual studio for Mac, added a few dependencies

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (1.1.2)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core (1.1.2)

and also imported the namespaces. However, when I create a new `HomeController` class and try to inherit from the `Controller` class

```
public class HomeController : Controller
```

I get a red squiggle line and an error:

> the type of namespace name 'Controller' could not be found".

Also, I can't seem to find the `project.json` and `csproj` files in my project.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core sdk? https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

Comment: Yes, because when I create a project from a template I don't get any errors. I only get an error when I create an empty project

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore` as well. This package contains references to a number of other packages that you need to build ASP.NET Core applications.

Try this working csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

> Also, I can't seem to find the `project.json` and `csproj` files in my project.

project.json has [been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537047/3191599), so you won't see it in your project.

You do have a .csproj file, though. Visual Studio for Mac is representing it as the LanguageFeatures element in the tree view. You should also be able to see it if you `ls` in your current directory.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to edit the csproj file directly, use NuGet to manually install at least the first two references above.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error. I used NuGet to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug. packages, and rebuilt my project.

Comment: @Inaloz_H Did you add Microsoft.AspNetCore as well? Can you post the contents of your csproj file?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved this by removing and reinstalling Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc then I rebuilt the project.