# xunit runner is not discovering test cases in Azure DevOps build pipline

Tags: .net, azure-devops, xunit, .xproj

I have a Web Application which was created on v4.6.1 framework and Visual Studio 2015 (.xproj and project.json combination). We have built the CI/CD pipeline using Azure DevOps where we are trying to execute the XUnit test cases. XUnit runner is not able to find the test cases. Is XUnit runner not compatible with .xproj and project.json type of projects when it comes to Azure DevOps? We are using Hosted VS2015 to build the project in Azure DevOps. Microsoft is already deprecated the xproj/project.json type of projects.

[xproj deprecation note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536978/is-project-json-deprecated)

Comment: You can use xunit with that combo of projects. maybe you are missing a certain nuget package or test-adapter. what packages do your tests reference ?