# I get Error while using npm start for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal, npm-install

I get this error when I type npm start.
This is my first time trying React Js. Please help

[image]

Comment: what error?  Please place all the details IN the question so we may best assist you here including the code and exact error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/npm-package-management

Comment: Note your "code" might be the exact steps - including version of Visual Studio etc. you need to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Did you ensure you ran `npm install` first? Did you check the log the error produced? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. Post errors as text and not screenshots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use NPM and install packages inside Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208056/how-to-use-npm-and-install-packages-inside-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37935524/125981

Comment: and please copy paste all error here provide more information, basically top half of your error is not visible in the picture