# ASP.Net Core 2.1: How to use Gulp with npm for project dependencies

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, gulp, asp.net-core-2.0

Now that `Bower` is dead with ASP.Net Core 2.0, I need to find an equally effective way to minify/inject my dependencies from npm.

I installed `gulp`, and using `npm`, I'm updating all my dependencies into the `node_modules` folder in the root of my project. The next step is getting all the dependencies listed in my `package.json` file to be injected into the `wwwroot` folder of my project.

I was going along Shawn Wildermuth's tutorial: https://wildermuth.com/2017/11/19/ASP-NET-Core-2-0-and-the-End-of-Bower and his "**Better Solution**" requires the dependency directories to be listed in the `Gulp` file:

```
// Dependency Dirs
var deps = {
    "jquery": {
        "dist/*": ""
    },
    "bootstrap": {
        "dist/**/*": ""
    },
};
```

Then creating a task, to iterate through these directories:

```
gulp.task("scripts", function () {
    var streams = [];

    for (var prop in deps) {
        console.log("Prepping Scripts for: " + prop);
        for (var itemProp in deps[prop]) {
            streams.push(gulp.src("node_modules/" + prop + "/" + itemProp)
                .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/vendor/" + prop + "/" + deps[prop][itemProp])));
        }
    }

    return merge(streams);
});
```

**Can this be done without listing all of the dependency directories in the `Gulp` file?** And instead, scan the `package.json` file to carry specific files from the `node_modules` folder to the `wwwroot`?

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
        "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
        "gulp-uglify": "2.0.1",
        "rimraf": "2.6.1"
    }
}
```

And here's the rest of my `gulpfile.js`:

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='clean, min, scripts' Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

I've seen some solutions out there that simply take everything from the `node_modules` folder, but this would be a giant (unnecessary) upload to the server, something I wouldn't do.

Any help?