# How to add node_modules files in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Im using [this](https://github.com/BootstrapDash/Stellar) admin panel template and there are some node_modules scripts and files like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css">
```

And there is no node_modules folder of course.
Im new at .net mvc, before I was using scripting langulage like PHP and I was using npm. How to deal with this in .net as compiled language (c#) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use npm with ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935524/how-to-use-npm-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: While the link is for Core, the concepts remain. If you get stuck, you linked to a product, with their own support.

Comment: ASP.NET Core has different files than MVC. For example MVC don't have wwwroot so I think is not the same question. Thanks for your time

Comment: In the end its configuration of your task runner/s (compile, etc.) if you're going that route. Client files (css, js) are just that, client files, nothing special. The link you provided is if you're deving/contributor. If you're just going to _use_ their theme/framework, then in the end it's vanilla `js` and `css` - no difference in _any_ platform.