# Moving files from node_modules to wwwroot with gulp in VS2015 asp.net core 1.0 project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, gulp, asp.net-core-1.0

When I create a new ASP.NET Core 1.0 application I want to use npm instead of bower. So I delete bower.json and additionally delete everything pre-installed in the wwwroot/lib folder.

I add a package.json file to my solution with the following dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6"
}
```

However, NPM downloads all of the libraries to a node_modules folder in the root of my project.

I believe this is what Gulp is for. Can someone please tell me how I can use gulp to send the distribution files from node_modules to my wwwroot directory. If there are any tutorials out there that I was unable to find, please link.

Comment: There an answer [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636570/visual-studio-2015-asp-net-5-gulp-task-not-copying-files-from-node-modules)

Answer (score 2):

Read this article https://wildermuth.com/2017/11/19/ASP-NET-Core-2-0-and-the-End-of-Bower
I used this when I saw that there is bad support of bower in netcore 2.0

Do `npm install xyz` or `yarn install xyz` for each package in bower.json. Update gulp to copy stuff from `node_modules` to `lib`. Replace `bower install` with `npm install` or `yarn install` in `*.csproj` file.

Summary gulpfile:

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

// Old bower behavior would be "*" in before and "" in after but you don't want that much.
var webpackages = {
    "requirejs": {"bin/*": "bin/" }
    // ...
}

gulp.task("dist_lib", function() {
    var streams=[];
    for (var package in webpackages)
       for (var item in webpackages[package])
           streams.push(gulp.src("node_modules/" + package + "/" + item)
               .pipe(gulp.dest("lib/" + package + "/" + webpackage[package][item])));
}
```

Comment: Is it me or does `merge` not get used?